# High res icon and image asset studio

Tags: android

Image asset studio provides legacy icons. One of those is the `Google Play Store` icon. At first, I thought that upon publishing an app, that icon will already be available but there is this `High res` icon that must be uploaded on Play Console account.

1. If they are the same, where can I find the generated icon from Image Asset studio to use for the Play Console?
2. If not, how can I generate an icon shaped like this?

[image]

or any 512x512 pixels image I upload will automatically be shaped like this?

Comment: you can generate desired shape high resolution icon from [here](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.type=clipart&foreground.clipart=android&foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0.25&foreColor=rgba(96%2C%20125%2C%20139%2C%200)&backColor=rgb(68%2C%20138%2C%20255)&crop=0&backgroundShape=none&effects=score&name=ic_launcher)

Comment: @HemantParmar is there a plugin for android studio?

Comment: this [one](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7658-android-drawable-importer) might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Go `Drawable` > `New` > `Image Asset` > `Legacy tab` > Click next to generate the icons. You'll find the 512 x 512 icon in the root of src > main folder with a name called `ic_my_sample_icon-web.png`. Just right-click on the icon and select `Show in Files` / `Reveal in Finder`

Comment: Found it! Was searching in mipmap and drawable folders. Thanks!

Comment: Saved me some time. Thanks Debdeep.

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 3):

Depdeep accepted answer above is obviously correct. Yet the file can be also found straight from your project path. In my case it was:

...\AndroidStudioProject\App_name\app\src\main\ic_launcher-web.png